# Unable to use custom tooltip component in react ag-grid. Error: Could not find component props ,did you forget to configure this component?

Tags: tooltip, ag-grid-react

I have implemented custom tooltip same as example in the ag grid documentation. But still facing the error as shown in link when I hover on specified column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BIb9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to resolve this error by upgrading the version of ag grid to 27.1.0 and by adding tooltip values based on params.data keys

Comment: I spent days on this mate, wondering why a 100% correct code is not working, you are a true savior!!!